# Can I install an x64 driver with a test certificate WITHOUT disabling the driver signature?

Tags: driver, windows-7-x64, driver-signing

I'm developing a virtual driver and [QA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality_assurance) needs to check out the x64 version on several Windows 7 machines. I have strictly followed the instructions on generating a certificate for test purposes, but I still have some problems. So, I've done the following [steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548693.aspx):

```
Makecert -r -pe -n "CN=TestCertForWDK" -ss "TestCert" mccert.cer
```

I've added the following [two lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553563.aspx) in the installer to make auto certificate installation on the remote machines

```
certmgr.exe -add mccert.cer -s -r localMachine root
certmgr.exe -add mccert.cer -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
```

[And](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553618%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
Inf2cat.exe /driver:D:\Projects\MyDrv\package\ /os:7_X64
```

And finally

```
signtool sign /a /v /s "TestCert" /n "TestCertForWDK" mydrv.cat
signtool sign /a /v /s "TestCert" /n "TestCertForWDK" mydrv.sys
```

BTW, at first I've tried installing via devcon. It reported that "devcon succeeded", but the device in [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) was marked with yellow exclamation mark (not trusted signature).

Later, I've tried using hdwwiz - when I manually enter the path to driver (Have disk) - hdwwiz shows that driver has a signature and installation proceeds without any warnings. But after that, as I've already metioned, the device is not working because of invalid signature (yellow "!")

I have an account on [Winqual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winqual), but the driver is still in development state, and I don't want to pay money for submission yet. Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to install a x64 driver with my own `makecert.exe`-generated certificate and *without* disabling a driver signature on the end-user PC (this is not acceptable for me)?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you need to bypass "Kernel Patch Protection" (KPP, informally known as PatchGuard) to be able to install an x64 driver with a test certificate WITHOUT disabling the driver signature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to have it cross signed by Microsoft as well. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487315) for more details.

Even if you want to use your own test certificate, you need to make changes using the [BCDEdit tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542202(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
bcdedit.exe {boot-entry-guid} testsigning on
```

This will allow your test certificate to be used. This is the only way to use a test certificate.